# c++: "expected constant expression"

Tags: c++, expression, constants

I am getting an "expected constant expression" error in the last line of the following code:

```
int main() {
    const float a = 0.5f;
    const float b = 2.0f;

    int array_of_ints[int(a*b + 1)];
}
```

I guess this is due to the fact that `int(a*b + 1)` is not known during compile time, right? My question is: Is there any way to code the above example so that it would work, and `array_of_ints` would have size `int(a*b + 1)`?

Any help or insight into what is going on here would be appreciated :)

Edit: I realize vector would solve this problem. However, I want the contents of the array to be on the stack.

Comment: I guess you are using Visual Studio?

Comment: make the cast `const int` or remove the cast alltogether

Comment: Use `new` and dynamically allocated it on the heap

Comment: @EdHeal Better yet, std::vector

Comment: @Borgleader - correct

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  What you have works on the [oldest compiler](http://ideone.com/PvLwek) I can find online handles it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `const int`:

```
int main() 
{
    const float a = 0.5f;
    const float b = 2.0f;
    const int s = static_cast<int>(a * b) + 1;

    int array_of_ints[s];
    return 0;
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/WfGw4r)

Note that this works on the oldest compiler I have access to at the moment (g++ 4.3.2).

Answer (score 6):

Declare the two constants as `constexpr` (unfortunately only available since C++11):

```
int main() {
    constexpr float a = 0.5f;
    constexpr float b = 2.0f;

    int array_of_ints[int(a*b + 1)];
}
```

Alternatively (for C++ prior to C+11) you can [use an `std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265819/493122).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did not know about constexpr! I do not want to use a vector, because I want the contents of the array to be on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using C++11 then use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) :

```
std::vector<int> array_of_ints(int(a*b + 1));
```

This will cause the vector to pre-allocate the specified space and will initialize all the ints to zero.

Comment: @DaleWilson, to be honest he talked about `std::vector` 1 or 2 minutes before I did. I did repeat it only for completeness.

Comment: @DaleWilson, I agree. But I can guaranteed you that this is not one of those. :)

Answer (score -1):

An “expected constant expression” error occurs when one tries to declare an arrays' size during runtime or during execution.
This happens because the compiler cannot; first, calculate the array size and then allocate that much space to the array.
A simple solution is to declare arrays with const int e.g **array[45]**
Another way to do it is to make a dynamic array :
    int array_name = new int [size ];